# meteor package d3

Tags: meteor

So I went over the instructions in question How to build a Meteor package and created one for the visualization library d3 using this code

```
Package.describe({
 summary: "Make cool visualizations with d3"
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use('d3', 'client');
  api.add_files('d3.v2.js', 'client');
});
```

I ran the meteor script from my github checkout (same place where I added this package). Then I created a new meteor app, but I still don't see d3 is getting included... Did I miss a step?

Comment: did you run `<location to your meteor> add <your package name>` ?

Comment: No I think that is what I'm missing but should it be then just meteor add d3? or what other command should I type in terminal?

Comment: ohhhh right right right gotcha

Comment: hmm still nothing... I'm wondering if my previous version of meteor is the one that is still running. After executing the meteor script that contains the new package I created a new meteor app. I'm assuming that my new app uses now the new meteor... right now I get "no suck package" when I do meteor add d3

Comment: running `which meteor` should tell you where meteor is running from, so you could see if it is indeed the meteor you intend to run. Also i'm not sure if meteor searches some global list of packages or if it resolves locally.

Comment: yup it's still using my /usr/local/bin/meteor copy instead of the other one. I'll try to make the change right there. Thanks for all the help greg!

Comment: ok so it works now. I had to rm -rf my original meteor and then run sh install.sh from the cloned one which contains d3 pakage. wuuuu time to play. again thanks man

Comment: No worries. Glad to help! I added an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're running your custom version of meteor and not the default install.

Then run `<your meteor> add <your package name>` from the project's root directory.

Answer (score 2):

One point to add to the above. With d3 I get errors from Meteor until I remove the 'server' reference in the package file above.

Comment: yup I was getting this errors to. A pull request has been submitted to meteor that includes d3 library only with the client chunk needed. I've now switched the question to have the working code in the question