# Get Three.JS working with meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, three.js, meteorite

I'm trying to use Meteor with Three.JS. The meteorite package I'm using for Three.JS is here: https://github.com/nozpheratu/three-meteor However, while I can do basic Three.JS functions, I am unable to do things such as instantiate a new Euler object (with the code `var x = new THREE.Euler(0,0,0,'xyz')`), I get the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. This happens with a few other miscellaneous things. I tried manually importing the Three.JS Euler class, but that told me that I was missing some other class, etc. Basically, is there a way to manually get three.js into Meteor? I tried adding the `three.min.js` to no avail either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this with three.js version 62 by making it a meteor package, then pointing the environment variable PACKAGE_DIRS to the root directory containing your local packages so they show up in "meteor list".

```
Package.describe({
    summary: 'threejs webgl 3D graphics library'
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.add_files('client/compatibility/three.js', ['client']);
    api.add_files('client/OrbitControls.js', ['client']);
    api.export('THREE');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question earlier that happened to be a bit old. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30796259/3450634

After playing around with Meteor for a few days, I've learned that it's not necessary to always have a package for a library you want to use. I cannot say this solution works for everything, but it has allowed me to use three.js without any hackery.

Place your `three.min.js` file within `client/compatibility` and create a new file within the client folder called `main.js` Within your `main.js` file enter the following code:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    // your three code here.
});
```

And viola! This should work perfectly fine. I'm using three.js r71 and  meteor v1.1.0.2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I'll update my answer tomorrow after some sleep.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @200OK Why did you copy what abarisone said?

Comment: @PeterDerouen I did't copy. We both reviewed your answer and selected the same option.This is the default text for that option.

Comment: @200OK Ah. Understood.

Comment: What I've noticed is you have to put your three code in main.js or else your canvas object won't load.